# Rails link_to inside form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a home page with a login form. The sign in works just fine, but the sign up button ends up trying to sign in the user, not redirecting to the sign up page as intended. This is the code I am using. Any idea how to fix this error? Thanks.

```
    <div class="well sidebar-nav">
       <br>

        <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
          <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
            <%= f.text_field :login, :required => false, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => "Username or Email" %>
          </div>

          <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
            <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password" %>
          </div>

          <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <div class="row-fluid">
              <div class="span4" style="margin-left: 1.25%; width: 50%">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                  <i class="icon-signin"></i>
                  <% f.submit 'Sign in' %> Sign In
                </button>
              </div>
              <% end %>


              <div class="span3" style="margin-left: -5%; width: 50%">
                <button class="btn btn-success">
                  <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
                  <%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path  %> Sign Up
                </button>
              </div><!-- /span8 -->
            </div><!-- /rowfluid -->
          </div><!-- /btn-toolbar -->
      </div><!-- /well -->
```

Update:
It turns out that putting the Sign Up link outside the button class solved the problem.

Comment: If you view the source of the page, what URI is `new_user_registration_path` being translated into?

Comment: And if you put a Sign Up link *outside* of the form, does that work properly?

Comment: Yes, if I put it outside the form, it works swimmingly. I'm using the registration paths from the devise gem.

Answer (score 2):

You should look to replace this code:

```
<button class="btn btn-success">
    <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
    <%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path  %> Sign Up
</button>
```

Your syntax here, to me, is inherently incorrect. The problem is that you're trying to put a link inside a button element, which will not work (it's against HTML syntax)

---

You might be looking for the [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) helper?

```
<%= button_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path, :method => "get" %>
```

---

This will create a small form on your page, which will take the user to the required URL. The difference will be that the user will only see the button and nothing else :)

Comment: Changing session_path to registration_path inverts the problem. Now both buttons lead to the Sign Up page.